# RequestJWTUserToken method occasionally seems to be returning wrong AccessToken

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using `RequestJWTUserToken` (docusign.esign.dll file version 4.1.1.0) to generate access tokens for a web application for each user, however occasionally the web application is sending documents from the wrong User's account.

I have logged the steps of the application, and when the error occurs,  2 (or more) of the my users are authenticating their UserIDs through our Integrator key at about the exact same time.

Each user is re-authenticating each time it is time to send a document.   The logs that I'm writing show that I am sending in the correct GUID in the parameter list to the RequestJWTUserToken method.   Any ideas on what could be occurring?

The method snippet is:

`private OAuth.OAuthToken  UpdateToken(string strUserGuid)`
        {
`try`
            {
`string ServicePointManager_SecurityProtocol_TLS_12 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServicePointManager_SecurityProtocol_TLS_12"];`
                System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection obj = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;

                if (ServicePointManager_SecurityProtocol_TLS_12 == null || ServicePointManager_SecurityProtocol_TLS_12.Equals("true", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = Tls12;

                System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

                var mtype = ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol;

                OAuth.OAuthToken authToken =
`ApiClient.RequestJWTUserToken(IntegratorKey,`
                                 strUserGuid,
`AuthServer,`
                                PrivateKey, 
`1);`
 
`AccessToken = authToken.access_token;`

`//set Account Property`
                if (Account == null) Account = GetAccountInfo();

                ApiClient = new ApiClient(Account.BaseUri + "/restapi");

                ExpiresIn = DateTime.Now.Second + authToken.expires_in.Value;


`return authToken;`
            }
`catch (ApiException ex)`
            {
`if (ex.Source.Contains("DocuSign.eSign") && strUserGuid != "")`
            {
`if (ex.Message.Contains("consent_required")) //send email with consent to sign link`
                    throw new Exception("DocuSign Consent Required for " + HttpContext.Current.Session["USER_FULLNAME"]);
`else`
                    switch (ex.ErrorCode)
`{`
                        case 400: throw new Exception("Bad Request: The requested UserID may exist in DocuSign, but there is an issue with the Docusign User Account.");
`default: throw new Exception("General Error");`
                    }
`}`
            else throw;
`}`
            catch
`{`
                throw;
`}`
        }

Comment: this sounds more like an issue to call support. information, logs, userIDs etc. etc. will be required to help you with this.

Comment: providing some code snippets might help too

Comment: Thank you.  I will try support.   Typically they tell me to ask Stack Overflow, so I figured I would try here first.

Comment: we can help here too if you provide at least the code snippet.

Comment: Thanks again.  I have updated the above with the method that contains the call to the SDK method RequestJWTUserToken.   Again, the variable strUserGUID does contain the correct user GUID at the time of the call, but apparently the token they are receiving back is incorrect, as they are able to send documents from the user's account that had authenticated at or about the same time.

Comment: the strUserGuid, which value do you pass in there? this has to be for the user which will make API calls on behalf of. This user must consent to the app. This may be the issue here.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, each user has a different strUserGuid value, and I logged the value being used for each call. All users have consented to sign.  The value being passed is correct for the various users of the app, but periodically the accesstoken returned by the call is apparently not for the user associated with the strUserGuid passed to the method, as the Docusign window opens in the wrong user's account.  Almost as if the token is cached somehow for a few seconds.

Comment: is it possible it is cached on your end?

Comment: do you have any idea about what is different when this is happening? is it a quicker switch between users? some other thing is different? cause it works ok most of the time, so try to isolate...

Comment: Thanks, for your thoughts on this.   We are not caching the user GUIDs on the server.  I've logged the calls to the JWT method, and it appears that the users that experience this issue are calling the method with the correct GUID, but launching the wrong DocuSign account, which is the account which authenticated just a few moments prior.    I could possibly construct a mutex surrounding this call, though I haven't seen that being used in any of the examples on GitHub, and have not much experience with threads.  Any thoughts (pros/cons) on using a mutex to isolate the code section?

Comment: " which authenticated just a few moments prior." in the same browser session?

Comment: No, two different devices being used.   The users are on separate Ipads.

Comment: well, I can't explain this. Basically you describe a serious bug, but our engineers are not aware of this. I cannot confirm there's a bug on our side, we'll have to open a ticket and work with you. We cannot proceed in stackoverflow, please contact our customer support for full engagement.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts.  I spoke with them today and did a code review to examine how we're initializing the ApiClient object before calling CreateEnvelope.  I feel like it must be something in the way we are using the SDK.   We're going to add some more logging to see if we can narrow down when/where it is occurring.   I'll update the issue with a resolution when one has been found.

Comment: Hello Jean, anything new here? did you find out something?

Comment: Still digging to find an answer.   My manager had the thought that perhaps it was the static variables that were in the class that I had used from GitHub.   I removed all of the static variables from the class, and I waited to see if the issue reoccurred.   Just heard this morning from our beta client that the issue had re-occurred over the weekend, so that did not fix the issue.

Comment: Update: Geoff in DocuSign support was really fabulous at figuring out what was going on with this issue!!   The issue we are experiencing is due to the apiClient being instantiated as a static variable within the Swagger CodeGen project, which is being used to generate the C# SDK.   A fix for this is not happening any time soon, so I'll be designing a workaround for now.

Comment: Jean, I'm sorry that we don't have the fix yet. Do you know how to workaround this issue? can you explain your fix?

Comment: Sorry to take so long to respond.  I've been heads down coding for a bit.   I've just moved out the workaround to our beta client for testing.   Haven't had the issue occur with this version yet, but the amount of traffic is lower due to the lockdown.   For the workaround, I'm just calling the Rest api methods directly using RestSharp.  It doesn't have all of the error trapping, etc in the SDK, so as soon as the SDK is fixed I will switch back.   I'm using the syntax derived from looking at it in Postman.     So far, so good.

Comment: well, was going to suggest using latest version (4.3) of the SDK, but if it works - don't touch it. How did you do the SHA256 encryption part?

Comment: I'll look into 4.3.  For the encryption, I found something online that used BouncyCastle to return an RSA key based on the private key.

Comment: can you share the link to what you found? thanks!

Comment: Sure.  Here is one that I found helpful:  https://www.csharpcodi.com/csharp-examples/Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl.PemReader.ReadObject()/ .  I believe there were also several on StackOverFlow.

Comment: thanks!................